# Insert Into Statement Circular References

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I keep getting an error message when trying to run the below code, keeps referring to [CID PERSON ID] as a circular reference.

```
        DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * from [tblOP_MASTER_FILE_PID]"
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [tblOP_MASTER_FILE_PID]" & _
                     "SELECT [CID PERSON ID] from tblOP_MASTER_FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between your two lines of SQL

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [tblOP_MASTER_FILE_PID] " & _
-------------------------------------------------^
                     "SELECT [CID PERSON ID] from tblOP_MASTER_FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight revision but got it working

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblOP_MASTER_FILE_PID ( [Person ID] )" & _
             "SELECT tblOP_MASTER_FILE.[CID Person ID] from tblOP_MASTER_FILE"
```